# RecyclerView with jerky scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Related this went through lots of blogs and links, got to know some deep insight behind this jerky scrolling, specifically expensive **onBindViewHolder()**, in my case it has to be heavy as bellow,

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PDFPageAdapter.MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int position) {
   PdfRenderer.Page currentPage = pdfRenderer.openPage(position);
    //W=564, H=771
    if (pageWidth==0) {
        pageWidth = currentPage.getWidth()*3;
        pageHeight = currentPage.getHeight()*3;

    }

    //BMP is around 15 MB(15*1000*1000 bytes)
    createdBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(pageWidth, pageHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    currentPage.render(createdBMP, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
    currentPage.close();

    //Glide.with(mContext).load(createdBMP).into(myViewHolder.ivForPDF);

    myViewHolder.ivForPDF.setImageBitmap(createdBMP);
    //GC free up bitmap memory
    createdBMP=null;
}
```

Since it is in a Custom PDF Renderer app, uses PdfRenderer native api to display page,
but fetched page quality is poor to display it on ImageView with(Width and Heigh match_parent) so **I have to multiply its dimension with three and create Bitmap** with same, gives nice quality but very **heavy Bitmap**,results jerky scrolling on the fly.
I tried following too.

- Create list in constructor with Bitmap, but gives very popular bitmap errors **outOfMemoryError**
- Also used **Glide**, but no luck.
- Also gone threw Google's suggestions for **effective Bitmap** loading, said downscale bitmap, but here I need bitmap bigger than the actual.

Any help is deeply appreciating, Thanks.

Comment: you should create bitmap before passing data to adapter

Comment: friend I did it earlier, since pages are hundreds i.e. hundreds of Bitmap in count and adding all them in list resulted **outOfMemoryError**.

Comment: well whenever you use a large bitmap then it results 'outOfMemoryError' so to fix 'outOfMemoryError' we use to rescale the image and make it small , but your are going otherway round which is against the rules so the results are as expected so you might should change your work flow / UI

Comment: Might be, but as I observed other PDF Reader app such as Acrobat, they are too good to achieve this with absolute smooth scrolling experience with full size good quality page view, any clue?.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set bitmap to imageview with glide as follows

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
yourBitmapObject.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
Glide.with(this)
     .load(stream.toByteArray())
     .asBitmap()
     .error(R.drawable.ic_err_drawable)
     .into(your_imageview);
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, but this is not the solution, there must be a way to lighten up **onBindViewHolder()**, by creating Bitmap somewhere else.

Comment: you can use asynctask to create your bitmap

Comment: also glide will load bitmap off your main thread so this will also be of help

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.

The problem turned out to be the height of the `item_layout`.
That is, it was a `match_parent`.
`wrap_content` is solved!